Derivation of Wald's general relativity equation 7.5.8 ; conformal transformation of Riemann tensor
I am trying to derive some nice properties of conformal transformation of Riemann tensor.
I found some formulas on appendix G on Carroll and appendix D in Wald, and recognize their starting point is nothing but equation 7.5.8. i.e., they replace $\partial \rightarrow \nabla$ and put the difference operator with the extraction of background part.
I am having problem of deriving equation 7.5.8 of Wald's general relativity textbook.

Here $C$ is a difference operation $\Gamma = \Gamma_0 + C$ in Wald's notation.
Following Wald's convention
\begin{align}
&\nabla_{b} w_c = \partial_{b} w_{c} - \Gamma^{d}{}_{bc} w_d \\
&\nabla_{a} t^{b} = \partial_{a} t^b + \Gamma^{b}{}_{ac} t^c
\end{align}
and


Collecting all(Definition of Riemann tensor and expression of covariant derivatives in connections), I notice that
\begin{align}
R_{abc}{}^{d} &=  - 2 \partial_{[a} \Gamma^{d}{}_{b]c} + 2 \Gamma^{e}{}_{c[a} \Gamma^{d}{}_{b]e} \\
&=- 2 \nabla_{[a} \Gamma^{d}{}_{b]c} -2 \Gamma^{e}{}_{c[a} \Gamma^{d}{}_{b]e}
\end{align}
and then plugging $\Gamma=\Gamma_0+C$, I have a different equation with equation 7.5.8 in Wald.
In the process my covariant derivatives on $\Gamma$ reads
\begin{align}
\nabla_{a} \Gamma^{d}{}_{bc} 
&= \partial_{a} \Gamma^{d}{}_{bc} 
 + \Gamma^{d}{}_{ae} \Gamma^{e}{}_{bc} - \Gamma^{e}{}_{ab} \Gamma^{d}{}_{ec} - \Gamma^{e}{}_{ac} \Gamma^{d}{}_{be} \\
 &
=\partial_{a} \Gamma^{d}{}_{bc} 
-\Gamma^{e}{}_{ab} \Gamma^{d}{}_{ec} + 2 \Gamma^{d}{}_{e[a} \Gamma^{e}{}_{b]c} \\
&=\partial_{a} \Gamma^{d}{}_{bc} 
-\Gamma^{e}{}_{ab} \Gamma^{d}{}_{ec} - 2 \Gamma^{e}{}_{c[a} \Gamma^{d}{}_{b]e} 
\end{align}
So in my computation it seems equation 7.5.8 in Wald's equation have typos....  Am I right? Is there something wrong with my calculation?

what is your final result? your expression for the riemann tensor in terms of coordinate derivatives and christoffel symbols looks correct to me. note that the $C^a_{bc}$ in wald are connection coefficients associated with a specific derivative operator $\nabla$ on your manifold, of which the christoffel symbols are a special case which  arises when $\nabla g_{ab} = 0$

I notice the point where i mis-understood the textbook.
Re-writing a Riemann tensor in terms of covariant derivatives was fine. But the problem was expanding connections and collect the terms properly. Here is the detail computation and the results (which agrees with Carroll and Wald, i.e. classical textbook.

